# PuLP not holding onto Integer Category

Tags: python-2.7, integer, glpk, pulp

So in my code I'm writing a Linear Program for different types of variables. There are 6. The first is an "x" variable for products and the remaining 5 are "w" variables for boxes (five different size boxes). I need all of these to be integers, however, in my output, I'm getting the x variables to be integers but the box sizes are all non-integers. I've tried 100 different things and I cannot figure this out.

for ind in varset:

```
    maxID = skunulldict[ind]
    sky = maxquant[maxID]
    globals()[ind] = pulp.LpVariable(ind, 0, sky, cat='Integer')
for indd in contset20:
    vn = contvendor[indd]
    capC = vv20[vn]
    globals()[indd] = pulp.LpVariable(indd, 0, capC, cat='Integer')
for indds in contset40:
    vns = contvendor[indds]
    capC = vv40[vns]
    globals()[indds] = pulp.LpVariable(indds, 0, capC, cat='Integer')
for indd in contset2b:
    vn = contvendor[indd]
    capC = vv2b[vn]
    globals()[indd] = pulp.LpVariable(indd, 0, capC, cat='Integer')
for indd in contset4b:
    vn = contvendor[indd]
    capC = vv4b[vn]
    globals()[indd] = pulp.LpVariable(indd, 0, capC, cat='Integer')
for indd in contsetcs:
    vn = contvendor[indd]
    capC = vvcs[vn]
    globals()[indd] = pulp.LpVariable(indd, 0, capC, cat='Integer')
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided definition of the variables seems to be ok.
You can try to print the category of the variable out to the console to verify their integer category at different parts of your source.

```
for x in modell.variables():
    print "Name:       ", x.name
    print "Category:   ", x.cat
```

Your problem is likely to be located in another part of your code. For a more advanced answer a working example or additional parts of the code are required.